# Show that two anti derivatives differ by a constant

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Today in Calc, we stumbled upon two anti derivatives (2 students had different approaches which we worked out) which are:
$$
\ln \left| \frac{\sin x - 1 - \cos x + \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 2 \cos x}{\sin x - 1 - \cos x - \sqrt 2 - \sqrt 2 \cos x} \right|
$$
and
$$
\ln \left| \frac{2 - \sqrt 2 \cos x + \sqrt 2 \sin x}{\sqrt 2 \sin x + \sqrt 2 \cos x} \right|.
$$

It turns out (fortunately) they they only differ by a constant, which according to the TI is approximately $0.88137358$ after taking the difference of their graphs. But to show algebraically that they are equal, I tried several approaches, but failed. Also, I am interested what that constant in exact terms would be. Jokingly, I told my students to do this for homework as we ran out of time, but honestly this one stumps me too. So please, any suggestions from you great thinkers out there?

Comment: Please post the integral.

Comment: Well, the constant is $\ln(\sqrt 2) +1$ (let $x=\pi/2$) ...

Comment: @SammyBlack, it is the integral of $\frac{1}{sinx+cosx}$  One student did it with the tangent half angle formula (weierstrass subs) the other student wrote the denom as $sin(x+pi/4)$ with a radical factor up front. The latter is a standard anti derivative. In my post both anti derivatives have that same coefficient up front, so that matches. It's the ln terms what is the issue

Comment: @DavidMitra your brackets are wrong, but you got that correct after playing around with your answer: $ln(1+\sqrt2)$ THANKS!!!

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we assume that both results are correct, then we just need to evaluate the following difference at a particular value of $x$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
C &=&\ln \left\vert \frac{2-\sqrt{2}\cos x+\sqrt{2}\sin x}{\sqrt{2}\sin x+
\sqrt{2}\cos x}\right\vert  \\
&&-\ln \left\vert \frac{\sin x-1-\cos x+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}\cos x}{\sin
x-1-\cos x-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}\cos x}\right\vert  \\
&=&\ln \left\vert \frac{2-\sqrt{2}\cos x+\sqrt{2}\sin x}{\sqrt{2}\sin x+
\sqrt{2}\cos x}\left( \frac{\sin x-1-\cos x+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}\cos x}{\sin
x-1-\cos x-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}\cos x}\right) ^{-1}\right\vert .
\end{eqnarray*}

For $x=0$ we find $C=\ln |- \left( \sqrt{2}+1\right)|=\ln \left( \sqrt{2}+1\right).$

If we want to prove that the two antiderivatives differ by a constant, then we can express $\sin x$ and $\tan x$ in terms of $t=\tan \frac{x}{2}$ to obtain a rational function in $t$, which we will then simplify until we get a constant. Since

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sin x &=&\frac{2\tan \frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan ^{2}\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{2t}{1+t^{2}}
\\
\cos x &=&\frac{1-\tan ^{2}\frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan ^{2}\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{1-t^{2}
}{1+t^{2}},
\end{eqnarray*}

we have that

\begin{eqnarray*}
C &=&\ln \left\vert \frac{\left( 2-\sqrt{2}\frac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}+2\sqrt{2}
\frac{t}{1+t^{2}}\right) \left( 2\frac{t}{1+t^{2}}-1-\frac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}-
\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}\frac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}\right) }{\left( 2\sqrt{2}\frac{t}{
1+t^{2}}+\sqrt{2}\frac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}\right) \left( 2\frac{t}{1+t^{2}}-1-
\frac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}\frac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}\right) }
\right\vert  \\
&=&\ln \left\vert \frac{-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left( t-1-\sqrt{2}\right) \left(
2+\sqrt{2}\right) \left( t+\sqrt{2}-1\right) ^{2}}{\left( t-1+\sqrt{2}
\right) \left( -2t-1+t^{2}\right) }\right\vert  \\
&=&\ln \left\vert \frac{-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left( 2+\sqrt{2}\right) \left(
-2t-1+t^{2}\right) }{\left( -2t-1+t^{2}\right) }\right\vert  \\
&=&\ln \left\vert -\left( \sqrt{2}+1\right) \right\vert  \\
&=&\ln \left( \sqrt{2}+1\right) .
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks, this looks nice. We know that the two anti derivatives are OK because we graphed it and took the difference of the graphs. It is a constant which turns out to be the one stated earlier. We then went into the trig mode and trying to prove one anti derivative into the other, meaning working with one trig expression and converting it into the other. That turned out to be nearly impossible. But your approach by subtracting the natural logs (and getting a constant) is certainly a worthwile approach.

Comment: @imranfat You are welcome. The use of the tangent half angle formulae simplified the computation very much.